# Create NavBar to do Action

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm learning to use React-Native and I'm in trouble with this kind of problem.

What I should do is to create a Navbar custom for a page that allows me to insert on the right a text that is visible depending on the user's role. (In particular, this text allows you to logout to a specific user role.)

At the moment I have implemented this functionality for all the user.

In the page where I put the Route and the Scene (*I Use Router-flux*), I have initialized the logout:

```
static logout() {
User.clearLoggedUser();
App.redirectLogout();
}



render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <Scene
            key="homepage"
            component={Homepage}
            type="reset"
            leftTitle="Home"
            leftButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
            onLeft={() => Actions.authentication()}
            rightButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
            rightTitle="Logout"
            onRight={() => App.logout()}
            navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#64c7c0" }}
          />
```

So, in the Homepage I have ,in the top right of the app, the logout (but it is for everything not for some Role).

In the Homepage I take the roles:

```
class Homepage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        const Roles = global.user.data.Person.Roles
```

So if {Roles} is equal to "Some Role" he shouldn't click (and see) the logout button.

How can I do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by: 'So, in the Homepage I have ,in the top right of the app, the logout (but it is for everything not for some Role)'

Comment: Does it always just say 'Logout'?

Comment: It is a logout button but every user can logout

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to implement some more logic up where you render the scene. try something along these lines:

```
static logout() {
User.clearLoggedUser();
App.redirectLogout();
}

render() {
    return (

      // These variables could also be stored in the state, 
      // depending on when/if they change and the scope you need them in.

      let currentRole = global.user.data.Person.Roles; // Or wherever the 
                                                // current role is stored

      let isLoggedIn = // boolean value to hold if anyone is logged in or not

      <Router>
      <Scene
            key="homepage"
            component={Homepage}
            type="reset"
            leftTitle="Home"
            leftButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
            onLeft={() => Actions.authentication()}
            rightButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}

            rightTitle={isLoggedIn ? "Logout " + currentRole : ""}

            onRight={isLoggedIn ? () => App.logout() : null}

            navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#64c7c0" }}
          />
```

So you need some logic on the right button that tells whether or not it should display and whether or not it should be clicked. You can also create a variable Logout button using the current user's role, but you need to access that role name one scope higher than the Homepage.

The above code would result in the right button saying 'Logout Manager' if the current role Manager was logged in, and if nobody was logged in, right button would say nothing and have a null click action.

Comment: The problem is that in this page global.user.data.Person.Roles; is not defined and I receive an error.

Comment: Is it defined in your original implementation when called in the Homepage component?

Comment: Yes it is defined in the homepage